# Object lock in java with some attributes values

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I have one object

```
public class MyObject{
 private int id;
 private String source;
 private String entityId;
 private string value;

//setter getter

}
```

//method in service

```
public syncronized void processCalc(MyObject o){
 //object processing code

}
```

here I used synchronized so whenever some outside thread will call they will wait if the method is used by 1 thread

Now I need to change it to have some condition. 
The same method should be used for synchronized and async based on some condition

if an object with source=ABC and entityId=123 already processing and coming thread has Object with source=ABC and entityId=333 then It should allow without Wait. If the same object with source=ABC and entityId=123 coming from diff thread then this should go to in Waiting state until first will complete the process.

So I need to make same method should be syncronized only when it meet some conditions.

```
1) if Coming Object is same as object already processing, then it should wait
2) If coming object is diff than already processing object then it should allow to proccess at the same time, no need to wait
3) same object I mean entityid and source is same
```

**NOTE: Here Value can be diff so that we need to implement such kind of logic**

Comment: are those the exact same objects, i.e. referring to same location in the memory? or they just have the same values ?

Comment: they will have same value only entityId and source.

Comment: I want to syncronize the thread only when other thread of same entityId and sourceCode processing. If some threads doesn't match with entityId and sourceCode already processing, can go async, they don't wait.

Comment: can Semaphore help on this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to put the lock on Object itself here

```
public  void processCalc(MyObject o){
 synchronized(o){
 //object processing code
}
}
```

Don't create new Object when values will be same next time , create the new object only when values will be different , i think this will serve your purpose , because there is one lock per object. So next time when values will be same and same object will be passed then it will wait for the existing lock to get release.And in the second case when object will be different it will proceed without wait.